# Uniting tags hamming-numbers and smooth-numbers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

One has 9 questions, the other 6. They are not exactly the same but are very closely related.

So, should this be done? Right now, I've [suggested "smooth-numbers" as tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hamming-numbers/synonyms) for "hamming-numbers", and if this comes through, I intend to go over the 6 of them and change the tag on these questions.

Is is the right course of action? If you support this, please vote at my tag synonym suggestion.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for putting the right tags here!